# geom_hex and ggmap lat/long misallignment

Tags: r, ggplot2, hex, latitude-longitude, ggmap

I am new to geo-mapping and wanted to produce a hexagonal heatmap over a geographic map of Canada.

I have latiude and longitude within my original data set, and I even have a variable I wish to use to produce the "heat" of each hexagonal tile placed on the map, but I am encountering 2 problems.

1) it appears as if there is a vertical translation applied to each coordinate.

2) I do not know how to show "heat" of another variable and not show density for the heatmap.

My data is given as follows:

```
map<-get_map(location='Canada', zoom=3, maptype = "terrain",
         source='google',color='color')

dat<-data.frame(cbind(c(47.00735, 47.36228, 47.40399, 48.08666,47.57196, 47.63742),
c(-52.95892, -53.29399, -52.79987, -52.89429, -53.27813, -52.92653),
c(86301.14, 1017390.34, 2662332.67,  473139.73, 8251899.99,  167512.52)))

names(dat)<-c('Longitude','Latitude','Rating')
```

Now the interesting thing is, when I run the following code, I get a hexagonal heat map with respect to density:

```
  ggplot(dat, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,color=Rating))+
  stat_binhex(na.rm=TRUE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red","blue"),na.value=NA)
```

I get this output:

[image: this output]

What I would like is a hexagonal heatmap where heat is shown by the Rating field.

Next, when I add a google map layer with the following code:

```
 ggmap(map)  +
 ggplot(dat, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,color=Rating))+
 stat_binhex(na.rm=TRUE)+
 scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red","blue"),na.value=NA)
```

I get the following error: `Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`

If anyone know hows to remedy these issues, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So it turns out that you can't use the `ggmap` function with the `ggplot` function. A minor change to the last code would be the following: `ggmap(map)  +
  coord_cartesian()+
  stat_binhex(data=dat, aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,color=Rating),na.rm=TRUE)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red","blue"),na.value=NA)`.

Comment: Side note: Looking at your map it seems you have confused latitude with longitude. lat=-53,lon=47 is not in Canada but between South Africa and Antarctica, It should probably be lon=-53,lat=47 which is in Canada (Newfoundland).

Comment: After looking into this into more detail, it appears that switching to cartesian coordinates creates this shift that was observed. Does anyone know how to convert Cartesian coordinates to Geographic Coordinate System coordinates?